# Symfony3 get the value of a non mapped field in event listener

Tags: addeventlistener, symfony

Trying to make a form that a user chooses an option and depending on their choice loads additional fields. So far I have a UserSignupType:

```
class UserSignupType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('userType', ChoiceType::class, array(
                'choices' => array(
                    "Subscriber" => "Subscriber",
                    "Friend" => "Friend"
                    ),
                'expanded' => true,
                'mapped' => false
                ));

        $builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
            function (FormEvent $event) {
                $form = $event->getForm();

                $usertype = $form->get('userType')->getData(); //updated per JBaffords answer

                if($userType == "Subscriber")
                {
                    $builder->add('agency', EntityType::class, array(
                        "class" => "\AppBundle\Entity\Agency",
                        "label" => "name"));
                }
                elseif($userType == "Friend")
                {
                    $builder->add('phoneNumber', PhoneNumberType::class, array(
                        'default_region' => 'US',
                        'format' => PhoneNumberFormat::NATIONAL));
                }
            }
        );
    }

    // ...
}
```

not sure if the getData method is the right method to use, and if it is, i need to somehow get the "userType" field out of it. I cant call getUserType because its not an actual mapped property and I don't want it to be. It simply decides the fields to show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the value for any form element (mapped or unmapped) by doing:

```
$form->get('fieldName')->getData();
```

`get()` returns a [`Form`](http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.html) object, so if you have a nested form, you can continue to call `->get('nextFieldName')` on each child until you get to the form element you need.

The value returned from `getData` for a form is going to depend on (amont other things) the mapping of its child elements. If the form has no children, then its value is its value; the mapping just determines whether that value is populated into its parent's data.

In your specific case, to get the data for the `userType` element, you would do:

```
$userType = $form->get('userType')->getData();
```

Comment: This seems right however with my current code I initially get a form with radio buttons "Subscriber" and "Friend"...  Based on which one is clicked I want the remainder of the form to load. Right now when one is clicked nothing happens... Not sure if I'm using the right functions, thinking I might need some JS/Ajax to do that? I was following this cookbook page http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#dynamic-generation-for-submitted-forms

Comment: @snoop168 Yes, so, you'll want to `$userType = $form->get('userType')->getData()`. `$form` is the main form; it's data isn't going to have the value you want because `userType` isn't mapped. But if you get the `userType` field (subform), *that* will have the data you need.

Comment: I think I understand the what you're saying but I dont think it fully covers what I'm trying to do, and that might be my fault because I dont even know if i am on the right track. With all the above code including your suggestion, only yields me a form with 2 radio buttons (which is what I want to start) but once one of the radio buttons is chosen I want the form to immediately update with the "sub form". This sub form will be different depending on which radio button is chosen. Right now you select a radio button and nothing happens.

Comment: is my event listener correct?? or i'm suspecting that I'll need some Javascript to dynamically update the form, or I'll need to submit this form with just the 2 radio buttons (one seclected) and then the controller decides the next set of fields (form to render)...

Comment: Ah, yes, you're right about that; you will want some ajax to refresh the form. Your event listener looks fine, apart from the `$usertype` case typo. (Alternatively, If you can't use ajax, you could instead include the fields on the form all the time, but selectively display them with css and only validate/process them based on the submitted userType.)